# Allow crosstalk between AWS security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a webserver and redis instance set up on aws. The webserver is in the following groups:

```
sg-allowSshFromMe
sg-allowHttpon80FromAnywhere
```

The redis instance is in the following groups:

```
sg-allowSshFromMe
sg-allowTcpOn6379FromWebserverSecurityGroup
```

However my webserver cannot connect to the redis instance; If I add an exception for the webservier ip to the redis security group it works; It just doesnt work with an exception for the webserver's security group. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: sg-allowTcpOn6379FromWebserverSecurityGroup allows incoming 6379/TCP from the default security group (one of three, total) associated with the web server?

Comment: @Jameson I just tried adding them both to the default security group which allows all traffic from the default security group; Still facing the same issue though

Comment: Post your SG rules here, also check firewall at both instances. Check the redis service is listening the proper IP, and you're connecting to that IP.

Comment: @"Matt Houser" was right, I was trying to reach my redis instance by its public ip; the redis security group's exception for the webserver security group only would know to allow requests from private ips through. Excellent call!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating rules in your security groups to allow connections from other security groups, you must ensure that your network connections are made to the target servers by their **private IP address** and not their public IP address.

When you connect to a server by it's public IP address, the connection exits your VPC and re-enters the VPC. When this happens, AWS loses the knowledge that it came from the source security group.